# new PR includes changes from older PR in Github

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have created 2 PR's to a repo; I was making changes to the new PR and did a

```
git pull upstream/master
```

and then create a new branch with `git checkout -b <new-Pr>`
and modified a file and did `git add .` and then `git commit` and `git push origin <new-Pr>` by doing this my files which I modified from older PR(which was not needed) also appeared in the new PR. How can I rectify the same?

Comment: Are they jammed into one commit or multiple?

Comment: I needed to change only 1 file, but when i squashed some 40 odd files got added to my PR which is from other PR's, which i don't need it to be included.

Answer (score 0):

You could rebase on top of another base branch:

```
git rebase --onto new-base old-pr-branch new-pr-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after much headaches I found this as a solution

```
git reflog
```

which shows my commits and rebased logs

then i choose to go back to the state by the help of comments and

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{80}
```

Then i finally do

```
git push --force
```